# Term Rebound in Yoga setting

Tags: meaning

In my book about Yoga, the author continuously repeats after a description of an asana "Follow this pose with a Rebound".

Like:
Bend forward, gently close your eyes and look towards yourself. Follow this pose with a rebound.

Since this is a static pose, I can’t find a translation, that makes sense in this context.
Am I missing a meaning, that would fit?

Comment: [What is a rebound?](https://www.shantiatma.com/yin-yoga-teacher-training/what-is-a-rebound/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=what-is-a-rebound) suggests that this isn't a standard English usage of the word.

Comment: That makes more sence then the translation of the word. THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in Yin Yoga, "a rebound" is a period of rest between the poses. You lie on your back and do nothing. https://www.shantiatma.com/yin-yoga-teacher-training/what-is-a-rebound/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=what-is-a-rebound

I think you're actually asking a question about yoga rather than English :)